# Singleton Enforced Classes?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

What's the purpose of using Singleton Enforced classes and does anyone have any examples of how to create/use them?

I was told I could do global variables (session) by using this idea, is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the Singleton Pattern is to make sure only a single instance of some object exists. It is usually used in flex to add Global State to a project. In other words, it allows you to do things like set and have access to global variables from anywhere in your application.

```
package {

  [Bindable]
  public final class AppGlobals {

    public static var _instance:AppGlobals;

    public function AppGlobals( enforcer:SingletonEnforcer ){
      if( enforcer == null ){
        throw new Error( "You can only have one active instance of AppGlobals.");
      }
    }

    public static function getInstance():AppGlobals {
      if( _instance == null ) _instance = new AppGlobals( new SingletonEnforcer );
      return _instance;
    }

  }

}

class SingletonEnforcer {}
```

To use this, you should instantiate your AppGlobals at the highest level of your application (main.mxml or whatever your top level is), by doing something like this:

```
private var _appGlobals:AppGlobals = AppGlobals.getInstance();
```

Then, anywhere in your application you can instantiate a copy of AppGlobals the same way, and have access to a global state of information.

To answer the second part of your question, yes, you can use this to setup global session variables in your application. Some people debate whether it is the best way to approach this (surely not ideal for every single situation), but I have found it useful.

Hope this helps!

Comment: wow, fast answer!! so looking at your code, the getInstance is basically what ensures that this is only created one time?

Comment: Good answer but I feel that I must add that Singletons are an anti-pattern since it makes your code less maintainable.  You should look into application frameworks like Parsley, RobotLegs or Swiz to inject those instances into your application.

Comment: @marcus, the getInstance function is there so that it returns the same instance.  The SingletonEnforcer class (at the bottom) is made so nobody can do `new AppGlobals`.

Comment: @marcus, Well, sort of. The constructor technically 'ensures' only one instance is created. The getInstance() method is what a) creates the first instance and b) returns that instance from thereon.

Comment: I don't do a lot of ActionScript programming, but still, it makes me sad that it doesn't allow private constructors.

Comment: Yeah, J_A_X, I do agree with you. This is technically an anti-pattern and is frowned upon in a lot of cases. It is useful in many though!

Comment: this is AS3, make that `getInstance()` a getter :D

Comment: @eaj - of course, true singletons would require this. It was an AS design decision, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep in mind the following. Singleton shouldn't solve lack of application design and used as global entry point. The only valid usage of Sinltone is ensure if there is **only one** instance of particular class (see also Multiton to control number of instances).

So you should think twice or even more times before deciding to use Singleton. Should you restrict number of instances of particular class? What if there will be more than one single instance — does it break domain model or something?

Anyway do not use Singletons and statics for solving architectural problems to have global entry point. Using Singltones you can spend a lot of time in future refactoring your application.

Comment: Oh, well I Was told (by manager) that i have to use singleton in the case i am making. unfortunately i don't have a lot of say. i think the solution before will work, but i will test it first. tHanks for the info!

Comment: Just remember that Singleton won fame as Antipattern. You'll make sure this fact in you'll try to use unit testing with your application. The impossibility of unit testing of Singletone enforced application is the best indicator of that Singleton's nature.

Comment: +1.  Prefer composition of parts (Inversion of Control) over Singletons.  Singletons are certainly anti-patterns and should be avoided.  Simply search for "singletons evil" in Google and you'll see some examples of this.  If your boss is telling you that you need a Singleton, then you might consider talking your boss out of it.  That being said, the pattern that @andrewpthorp gave is the closest you will get to creating a Singleton in ActionScript 3.  You cannot, technically, implement the pattern purely because you don't have access to private constructors.